# input string was not in a correct format. GenerateEditingElement combobox datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, frameworkelement

Exception: *Input string was not in a correct format*

I am not sure how i am getting this. It only happens when i try to re-enter the cell when a value is already placed. So if the user wants to edit what they previously entered it produces this exception.

I have this override so i can utilize the IsEditable property.

It produces the exception after the function GenerateEditingElement is run.  If i skip over the code for debug i get this.

*Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).*

```
public class DataGridComboBoxColumn : DataGridBoundColumn {
    public Binding ItemsSourceBinding { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMemberPath { get; set; }
    public string SelectedValuePath { get; set; }
    public object ItemSource { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIndex { get; set; } = -1;

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) {
        var textBox = new TextBlock();
        if (Binding != null) {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBlock.TextProperty, Binding);
        }
        return textBox;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem) {
        var comboBox = new ComboBox { IsEditable = true };
        if (Binding != null && ItemsSourceBinding != null) {

            comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = DisplayMemberPath;
            comboBox.SelectedValuePath = SelectedValuePath;

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox, ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, Binding);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(comboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, ItemsSourceBinding);

        }
        return comboBox;
    }

    protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs) {
        var comboBox = editingElement as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox == null) return null;
        if (SelectedIndex != -1 ) { comboBox.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndex; } else { comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1; }
        comboBox.Focus(); // This solves the double-tabbing problem that Nick mentioned.
        return comboBox.Text;
    }

    protected override bool CommitCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement) {
        return base.CommitCellEdit(editingElement);
    }

    protected override void CancelCellEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement, object uneditedValue) {
        base.CancelCellEdit(editingElement, uneditedValue);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<local:DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Prod #" x:Name="cboProd" Width="60" Binding="{Binding ProductNum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="ProductNum" SelectedValuePath="ProductsID" ItemsSourceBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PurMaterialEntry}}, Path=PDN}"/>
```

PDN is my collection of product numbers of the project in the combobox next to it.

**What i am looking for.**  
- I want it to clear the cell on re-entry. 
- The project ComboBox in the grid controls this one.

[Image showing that the combobox works during entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXM9p.png)

**But if i have to modify the product D101 the exception occurs.**

Comment: Hi, just for clarification, does your code break after it has returned the Combo Box or  before that? Either ways could you indicate the line it broke on?

Comment: You are returning a combBox but the return type of the method is FrameworkElement

Comment: @Jacob JA Shanks  I don't know where it breaks at. it just tells me its (typically system or framework code)

Comment: Should be okay because `FrameworkElement` is a base of `ComboBox` (`ComboBox -> Selector -> ItemsControl -> Control -> FrameworkElement`)

Comment: @pm101 it works great until i Re-enter the cell.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243235/overriding-datagridtextcolumn (seems related - not sure if it answers anything though)

Comment: This issue might need more information. From the information we have, I would guess it's down to how the combo box is being implemented in the DataGrid. Can you include this code in the question?

Comment: @AnthonyEckstorm It would be much better to do this with a CellTemplate in the XAML. In WPF, generating UI in C# code is painful, error-prone, and rarely done. I agree with Jacob that we need to see more code to resolve this issue, but the real solution is to abandon this line of inquiry and do it in XML.

Comment: @pm101 i tried the suggestion you gave. Same results.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The only issue with cell template is i need to be able to change the values in the combobox based on the selection in the cell next to it. I have never been able to get that to work. I would be interested if you could lead me down the right path? :)

Comment: @AnthonyEckstorm Make your row object a viewmodel that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Put the logic you mention in the setters in the viewmodel. Have the one property update the other. Then let the bindings do the work in the UI.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was able to get it working with your suggestion. Thanks!